# In NodeJS REPL, how to print to standard out?

Tags: node.js

I create a simple variable like below and I want to print it. I made up the command print but that of course does not work. Is there an equivalent to that? I want it to display the output variable on the output like it shows return values when I execute x.gatesAgeOnDate()

```
    var billGatesBirthday = '10-28-1955';
    print billGatesBirthday;

    exports.gatesAge = function() {
        return (new Date() - new Date(billGatesBirthday)) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365.25
    };

    exports.gatesAgeOnDate = function(dateOfInterest) {
        console.log('dateOfInterest');
        return (new Date(dateOfInterest) - new Date(billGatesBirthday)) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365.25
    };
```

Comment: Just console.log(billGatesBirthday)?

Comment: protip: don't work in the REPL, make a file like `myfile.js` and tell node to run that with `> node myfile`. Working in the REPL is both inconvenient (you don't get to undo mistakes, only overwrite them) and not how people who use Node, use Node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working in the REPL is a bit weird (most people, and I'd recommend you do too, make real .js files and then run that using`node realfile.js` instead. The ".js" is even optional) but: you have three options.

First, the universal way to do this in JavaScript is to use `console.log` (and related statements). This does what it says on the tin: it logs, to the console.

However, you're in the REPL, which means any commands you evaluate will also log their return value automatically. While in real Node runs (from file) you can only rely on `console.log`, in the REPL you can also just type the variable name and see the return value:

```
> var a = "cats":
undefined
> a
'cats'
```

Handy.

Finally, you're in Node, so you have direct access to the standard out pipe through [process.stdout.write](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout), so you can stream write to that. There is absolutely no reason to do this, but you can:

```
> var a = "lol";
undefined
> process.stdout.write(a);
loltrue
```

"that's not just a", no it's not, like mentioned above it's the thing you did *plus* the return value. `console.log` is kind enough to automatically insert a newline for you, process.stdout obviously doesn't. So we see the value of `a` printed, no newline, and then the return value of the stream write attempt, which is `true` because nothing went wrong. Don't use process.stdout for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(billGatesBirthday);
```

Always use console.log() to print anything using JavaScript.

Comment: Not if you're using the Node REPL. You can also take advantage of the fact that REPL always logs returns to the console, too.

Comment: REPL logs undefined on declaring variables and not the actual value.

Comment: Yes, obviously. The REPL logs returns, so you just type the variable name and hit enter. That returns, rather unsurprisingly, the content of the variable.

Comment: When in the REPL I type the line "for(i=0; i<10; ++i) { i }"  , only the last value, i.e. 9, gets printed. When I do ... console.log(i) , then all 10 values get printed (; plus an "undefined" , which represents probable the value returned by the for loop itself).